# IOS app crashes when launched on iPhone from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

[image]I have been working on a basic app all week that has been working fine. I was able to put it onto my iPhone 11 and run it with no issues, then suddenly this morning, the app gets stuck on the launch screen. The same thing happens when I try and launch on the simulator.

The ONLY error that pops up says "Error Decoding" and nothing else.

I have tried cleaning the Xcode folder, restarting Xcode,  restarting my computer, restarting my phone, and deleting the app and reinstalling it. Still no luck..

Is anyone familiar with this error? I did a search and surprisingly couldn't find anything useful...

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what did you use for decoding? a web call or something ?

Comment: did you tried adding *Exception breakpoint*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Update all yours softwares, like Xcode and IOs.
2. Open your code and before run, click on "Clear Building Folder"
3. Try to execute your code!

Thanks! Jean Santos.